# NSEntityDescription object not created in ios 6.1.3

Tags: objective-c

`NSEntityDescription` is working fine in Simulator iOS 6.0 but i am not able to run my code in iPhone device with ios6.1 and above Its give Exception like Terminating app due to uncaught exception '`NSInvalidArgumentException`', reason: `executeFetchRequest:error: A fetch request must have an entity.`

My Code is:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Wager" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
```

Comment: you might be running your app without actually deleting the previous build on device. Delete your build from device. In Xcode, do  - "clean" and re-run it on device.

Comment: deleted previous build but still not working..